# How to use file transfer in Ionic with cookies

Tags: angular, session, cookies, file-upload, ionic2

I am trying to upload an image using ionic native file transfer but the problem that backend using session. How I can upload a file and send a cookie, as I do that in regular HTTP post.

I tried with headers to set withCredentials to true but that not helped:

```
let options = {
    quality: 100,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
};
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'picture',
        fileName: new Date().getTime() + '.jpg',
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        chunkedMode: false,
        headers: {'withCredentials': true},
    }

    fileTransfer.upload(imageData, 'myurl', options1, true)
    .then((data) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, (err) => {
        alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how to handle that when backend use session?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to put `withCredentials: true` directly in the options instead of in the headers?

Comment: I solved problem with deleting web-view plugin